# Employee Training Tracker

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SharePoint 2013, I have the following 2 lists, noted below.

I need to copy the names of the 10 courses in the Course List over to the Main List and associate a new user's profile name (Person or Group) to each of the 10 courses. Once notified the user will complete the required course, upload their certificates and enter the Start and Expiry date in the Main List.

I will need to repeat the same process for each additional new user. I'll be also using the list to track the individual/overall status of who has/has not completed the required courses.

1. Main List: (contains the record of all users and the courses they've completed)

   - Profile Name: Person or Group
   - Course Name: Lookup (Course List)
   - Start date: Date and Time
   - Expiry Date: Date and Time
   - Attachments: Users upload their course certificate
2. Course List: (contains the name of the courses ( currently 10 courses) that the users must complete)

   - Course Name: Single line of text
   - Description: Single line of text
   - Frequency: Choice

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a project scope, not a question. You need to learn how to design forms, for example with InfoPath or with SharePoint Designer, create a parent/child relationship and how to write workflows. Then you can do what you describe. Or, hire a developer to create a custom solution.

Comment: I already have the 2 lists created and currently using it and I want to automate the process of moving the courses to the main list rather than doing it manually. So my QUESTION is, how can I do it, point me in the right direction and I probably can figure it out. I've tried different options but was not successful. I am a SharePoint end-user not a developer.

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification and details. Then post a comment to alert the people who are following the question. As a new user you may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could use workflow or event receiver to create the training certificate. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[How to: Automatically create a training certificate in SharePoint](https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/create-training-certificate-sharepoint-automatically/)

And there are some articles about the training template for your reference.

[Training Site Template – Part 1: Introduction.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2007/03/10/training-site-template-part-1-introduction/)

[Training Site Template – Part 2: Workflows.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2007/03/24/training-site-template-part-2-workflows/)

[Training Site Template: Part 3 – Custom Views and Forms.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2008/07/05/training-site-template-part-3-custom-views-and-forms/)

[SharePoint Employee Training Scheduling and Materials Template.](http://www.fastsharepoint.com/templates/EmployeeTrainingSchedulingandMaterials)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old thread, but this is exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm very inexperienced in Sharepoint so if someone could point towards some basic guides to accomplish this I'd be very grateful!